# Searching for strings in MySQL WHERE string LIKE string (wrapped in parentheses)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to return a search term with PDO, some of the strings are wrapped in `()` and when searching they don't show up.

Take for example `Strawberry (Ripe)` it shows when I use the `(r`

[image]

**But when I don't:**

[image]

Is there any way to match the string within the parentheses for a fuller more efficient search.

My Current Code:

```
public function getAllFlavoursSearch($search) {
    $query = "SELECT flavour_name, flavour_company_name FROM flavours WHERE flavour_name LIKE :search OR flavour_name LIKE :search2 OR flavour_name LIKE :search3 OR flavour_company_name LIKE :search4 LIMIT 0,100";
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':search', $search. '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':search2', '%' .$search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':search3', '%('.$search.')%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':search4', '%('.$search.')%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
return $this->resultset();
```

Comment: Well you would have to take this apart, so that you can search for `strawberry` and/or `ripe` separately …

Comment: What do you mean by "take this apart" can you please elaborate

Comment: I wonder how MySQL's [Natural Language Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) would cope with this...

Comment: Well you can not just go and search for `%strawberry r%`, because that will obviously not find `Strawberry (Ripe)` - you searched for something that has only a single space between `strawberry` and `r`, so this obviously doesn’t match. So, you would need to take this apart, and put placeholders in between as well, `%strawberry%r%`; or search for both “terms” separately, `WHERE flavour_name LIKE '%strawberry%' AND flavour_name LIKE '%r%'` .. depending on what exactly you want/need. (The second example would find `we are strawberry`, too.)

Comment: Oh, I see, is there is no way to match the parentheses in MySQL? Is it possible to use something like REGEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a shortcut. MATCH() function. change your query to this.

```
$query = "SELECT flavour_name, flavour_company_name FROM flavours WHERE MATCH(`flavour_name`, `flavour_name`, `flavour_company_name`) AGAINST (:search) LIMIT 0,100";
```

Comment: Returns nothing now.. Are those backticks or single quotes?

Comment: I'm seeing `General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`